# Valid Hostnames Set, Languages Set, but Still see Blackhatworld Ghost spam in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, spam

I am not sure why this is happening. Afaik, I've properly set my valid hostnames and languages to remove ghost spam and those fake languages. However, this one sucker of a bot continues to show up:

[image: RealTime stats still show this spammer, blackhatworld dot com]

[image: GA Hostname seems to filter properly]

Why is this still showing up in real time and how do I fix this?

Comment: You may need to ask this on the Google forums. I do not have an answer, however, if you are thinking this is a bug or something that you are missing in usage, the Google forums may get you an answer faster. Keep in mind that Google does monitor the forums and sometimes jumps in. G has a user here too, however, that user tends to be rather quiet these days.

Answer (score 1):

Real time doesn't apply record adjusting filters. They're applied afterwards. If your filters work, it won't show up in your stats tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @Yhorian, filters are in fact applied to real time data if you have them defined for that particular view. "If your data looks incorrect in Real-Time, check which filters are being applied to the view. It's best to use an unfiltered view when debugging tracking code implementations. Changes made to views may take up to two hours to reflect in Real-Time." https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en

Comment: So now that I see the valid hostname and language filter working (since all of the spam is gone), I don't see any of our social, direct, or organic search showing up. I know people are on our site because I see users making searches on our search engine - but nothing shows up in GA's filtered view (I have the unfiltered view to debug as well). Ideas behind this craziness?